# Error 1 Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'method group'

Tags: c#

I require help with a error (see title) all help appreciated. I have browsed through many pages of other people errors but none have seemed to solve it, also i am sorry if the code is not formatted properly

```
public void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string weight = (ExtractNumbers(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[2].GetElementsByTagName("td")[11].InnerText));
}

public void webBrowser3_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string salesrate = (ExtractNumbers(this.webBrowser3.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[2].GetElementsByTagName("td")[17].InnerText)); 
}

public void timer9_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    *if (weight >= salesrate)
    {
        i am getting this error with this IF statement
    }*
}

public static string salesrate(string expr)
{
    return string.Join(null, Regex.Split(expr, ""));
}

public static string weight(string expr)
{
    return string.Join(null, Regex.Split(expr, ""));
}
```

Comment: You have not include enough code for us to be able to help you, specificly you have not included the definition of weight and salesrate used in timer9_Tick.

Comment: Besides the compile error, strings probably aren't what you want to store your numbers as. It will compare the characters in the string and not the actual numbers. i.e. "2" will be > "10" because it will compare the '2' to the '1' and then say that the '2' is bigger.

Comment: You must have methods named `weight` and `salesrate`. Show those method definitions.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you are asking for, i don't know what "method" is can you give me a example of what i should be looking to post? sorry again

Comment: Yes, those things you added in the edit are called methods. Sometimes called functions or subrountines in other languages (or casual conversation). However, now it is not clear what you intend to do by comparing two strings with `>=` because `String` has no such operator. Also, it is not clear why you would want to compare a "weight" to a "salesrate".

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, here are the changes

```
string weight= "";
string salesrate = "";


public void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    weight = (ExtractNumbers(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[2].GetElementsByTagName("td")[11].InnerText));
}

public void webBrowser3_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    salesrate = (ExtractNumbers(this.webBrowser3.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[2].GetElementsByTagName("td")[17].InnerText)); 
}

public void timer9_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
      var parsedSalesRate = Double.parse(salesrate);
      var parsedWeight = Double.parse(weight);
      if(parsedWeight >= parsedSalesRate) {
          // ...
      }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
           throw;
    }
}



        public static string GetSalesrate(string expr)
        {
            return string.Join(null, Regex.Split(expr, ""));

        }
        public static string GetWeight(string expr)
        {
            return string.Join(null, Regex.Split(expr, ""));

        }
```

Comment: Error 1 'double' does not contain a definition for 'parse' @IsabelHM

Comment: Try a capital P in parse.